# Disable Sharedaddy in Feeds

Tags: rss

I am using Feedburner for my feeds and I am also using Sharedaddy from Jetpack to display the sharing icons. I'd like to disable these buttons in the feed, how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: What have your tried already? How are the icons added to the feed?

Comment: There is no option to disable or enable display in feeds, so I'm just running on default to display the sharing icons on posts.

Comment: How are the icons added _programmatically?_

Comment: I think Feedburner just reproduces the posts, as in http://feeds.feedburner.com/WordPressBlogsites, how do you take off the sharing icons?

Comment: I think Feedburner is using the feed output, not the regular blog post. So somewhere Sharedaddy adds these icons on the hooks `'the_content_feed'` or `'the_content'`. Find that code and add it to your question.

Comment: Yes it uses the source mysite.com/feed/. How can I control what appears in the feed from the WordPress end, maybe in functions.php? I could use a conditional to check if it is the feed page, and if yes unhook the sharedaddy icons.

Answer (score 2):

The icons are added to the feed per filter in [`modules/sharedaddy/sharing-service.php`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/jetpack/trunk/modules/sharedaddy/sharing-service.php):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display', 19 );
```

`sharing_display()` *does* check for `is_feed()`, so there shouldn't be a problem … seems to fail for no obvious reason.

You could add another check; something like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'disable_sharedaddy_in_feed' );

function disable_sharedaddy_in_feed()
{
    is_feed() and add_filter( 'sharing_show', '__return_false' );
}
```

Comment: Toscho with his beautiful minimal code.

Comment: till now it still displays them, not sure if it takes time for feedburner to show changes.

Comment: @drtanz Feedburner has a _force refresh_ button somewhere. I don't use it, so you have to find it on your own. :)

Comment: even after resyncing it still works the same, maybe there is something wrong with the theme :S

Comment: All other plugins were disabled when you tested it, right?